# Best way of version control, stable builds and exporting/ a project on multiple devices

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

today it's a shorter question I'd like to ask, to hear your opinions as I suppose some do this differently than others.

First of all,, I have an Android Studio project and am rather a novice on this subject of Android Development. That's why slight changes in the java or xml files could and did make my latest app unstable/ crashing.
Therefore I was asking myself wether Android Studio offers a way to backup stable builds - I could imagine this like a save-as option where you backup the working version and continue working on the the one but have a stable one backed up.
I know there's the export project function but I tried it out a couple of times and having worked on a project on the same device before, prior to reimporting a project causes an error and that's not the way I guess you should handle it in this situation.

I was looking at Google Cloud for using both version control and the option to commit new versions to the trunk and update them at a different location (different device). If that's the solution you propose, I need to look more closely into the documentation to get it up and running (set up the repository already but no clue how to commit changes/ versions).

So, long story short, what tool/ option do you prefer to have an export and a version control option unified for Android Studio?
Interested to hear and thankful for any advice on that!

Comment: Android studio has inbuilt VCS(version control system) to help the developers. You can enable it in your VCS-> enable version control integration. Also it provides popular remote VCS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions,

1. Just find your solution/project in your file explorer and back it up, if you need it again just open the project with Android Studio. (not the most popular one)
2. Use a version control system like git. [Link to tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-git-in-android-studio--cms-30514) (This is the most popular one), If u are unfamiliar with git, just google it and there are tons of examples and documentation. With git you can tag commits and after u mess up revert to the tagged commit

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed - this however helps me most, I was really looking for a walkthrough for git integration in Android Studio since I read the first answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Git is the simpliest.
It's supported by AndroidStudio and later on you can upload your project to GitHub to access it from anywhere.
You can use it with terminal and shorcut keys, incons as well.
You also can make separate branches in order to make and test more versions parallely.
For more info take a look at: https://git-scm.com/about
and of course github: https://github.com/
Regards,
Cs